# Wire connected only to positive terminal

Tags: circuit-analysis

I apologise if this is a very basic question but I hope you can help.

If I connect a wire to the positive terminal of my battery only, why do the electrons in the wire not flow out of the wire?

If the positive terminal consists of positive ions surely there is a lot of positive charge within this terminal attracting the electrons in the wire. The charge in the wire will be initially be equal due to the equal sum of protons and electrons. With there being an equal attractive and repulsive charge behind the electrons and a large attractive charge to the positive terminal why does this not result in a flow towards the positive terminal?

Why will the electrons not flow into  the positive terminal until the positive charge in the wire due to electrons that have left equals the positive ions remaining in the positive terminal.

Comment: Actually, they do. But the number of electrons required to move is very small, based on the capacitance between the wire and the negative terminal of the battery.

Comment: Actually they would move.   A little.  A very little.   A very very little.

Comment: `If I connect a wire to the positive terminal of my battery only` ... why would a wire be required to start the current flow?... the battery terminal is not insulated

Comment: The battery terminal is indeed insulated... by air.

Comment: @AndyW and air is a perfect insulator? don't think so...

Comment: @Solar Mike Nothing is a perfect insulator. Not even vacuum. But relative to a copper wire, air is a fantastic insulator. And cheap.

Comment: Can somebody explain why only a small quantity of electrons move? Why are they not sucked out of the wire towards the large positive charge of the terminal. I understand that they wouldn’t be replaced as there are no electrons backfilling them; there also wouldn’t be the push on them from the negative terminal, but what’s stopping a steady stream of negatively charged particles  flowing(until they are depleted) towards a positively charged terminal?